# link corresponding to plugin not part of robot model

Tags: gazebo-plugin, xacro

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am able to run the multi robot scenario example from the gazebo_plugins ROS pkg (indigo-devel branch) without a problem.

However, in the gui, there is no Model Link corresponding to the camera sensor as I would expect. All other links are shown, just not the plugin link. The camera sensor link *is* published correctly in ROS.

Looking at the [camera.xacro](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/hydro-devel/gazebo_plugins/test/multi_robot_scenario/xacro/camera/camera.xacro), the pattern (`link` tags followed by `gazebo` tags with the same name) seems to be the same as for those links which *do* show as part of the robot model.

Anything I'm missing?

```
<link name="${name}">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="1e-5" />
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="0.03" length="0.1"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="grey"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder radius="0.03" length="0.1"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
<gazebo reference="${name}">
  <material value="Gazebo/Grey"/>
</gazebo>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6919/link-corresponding-to-plugin-not-part-of-robot-model/) by [phil0stine](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/130/phil0stine/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Links that are connected via fixed joints are combined when URDF is converted to SDF. This could cause the camera link to disappear in simulation.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/130/phil0stine/) on 2014-08-28**:
Ok, so assuming I need to get that transform (say, world to camera), do you have a suggested approach? One might be to make the joint not fixed but it seems like there could/should be a better way.

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-09-02**:
I think the sensor will have a `pose` tag that you can use to get the sensor transform.